# File 'requirements.txt' in a Python package

Tags: python-3.x, package

I'm studying packages, and I have a question on creating a *requirements.txt* file.

If a module is imported from Python, does it need to be mentioned in the *requirements.txt* file or can be left out?

I know that for separate modules, they need to be pip installed. For those modules that need to be pip installed, should they be written in the requirements.txt file as 'pip install modulename'?

Answer (score 4):

The **requirements.txt** is a file where one specifies dependencies. For example, your program can have dependency on [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) or we can say the **requirements.txt** file in a Django project describes the packages that needs to be installed for successfully running a project.

Talking about the sub-modules: Suppose you have specified Django in the *requirements.txt* file, now you don't need to specify any sub-modules (like 'django.shortcuts') in the *requirements.txt* file. Because they are already included in the Django module.

Now one can easily use

> from django.shortcuts import path

in your .py files.

Now for separate modules (like pillow) that need to be specified in the **requirements.txt** file, you don't need to write

```
pip install pillow
```

You can just write pillow in a separate line with other modules like:

> django
>
> pillow

You can also use the below command to do so:

```
pip freeze > file_name
```

In your case file_name will be *requirements.txt*. This will add all the third-party module names in the *requirements.txt* file.